# excel custom number format with three conditions

Tags: excel, formatting, numbers

is there a possibility to use multiple conditions in Excel  number format?

I need following:

```
 number    format

  7000      7
  125       0
 -8054     (8)
 -149      (0)
```

when I use:

```
#,###, ;(#,###,)
```

it works well unless number is  less then -499, which is displayed as (0)

I've tried

```
[>=0]#,###, ;[>-500]("0");(#,###,)
```

and that works fine, but the problem is when the number less then 500 0 is not displayed.

So I've tried:

```
[<500],"0" ;[>=0]#,###, ;[>-500]("0");(#,###,)
```

but excel cannot accept this numbering format. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
#,##0,;(#,##0,)
```

Answer (score 6):

While Jean-François Corbett has the correct answer for the question's specific case, it does not answer the titular question of the OP.

It seems that Excel (and related spreadsheet software) has a fundamental limitation that it can only use two conditionals in custom number formats. Apparently, internally it is using 4 possible display categories: `number condition 1`, `number condition 2`, `other number`, and `text`. Setting custom number formats can only redefine the two number conditions. You cannot directly control the "other" condition.

So, a possibly more clear way of describing the conditional options for custom formatting:

```
[condition 1]custom format 1;[condition 2]custom format 2;other number format;text format
```

Where `condition 1` defaults to `>0` and `condition 2` defaults to `<0`.

Comment: The third part will be applied for any value not falling into conditions 1 or 2. so if condition 1 is <1 and condition 2 is >1; then third format will be applied to value 1, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

Custom Number formatting comes with this syntax, in this order. (more details at  www.DataPigTechnologies.com blog post [Improving the Default PercentFormatting](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/improving-the-default-percent-formatting/))

1. format for positive numbers
2. format for negative numbers
3. format for zero
4. format for text

Jean-Francois Corbett has the solution, but I thought I would offer the why some of your trys weren't providing you with the results you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you still looking to use more than two conditions to define Excel custom number formats, have a look at the answer over at stackoverflow to [How to use multiple conditional operators in a custom number format Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32614844/how-to-use-multiple-conditional-operators-in-a-custom-number-format-excel).

The key is to use conditional formatting.  With this you can set as many conditions as you want with each condition having a unique number format.