# How to use multiple conditional operators in a custom number format Excel?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

My brother asked my help formatting a Worksheet. He wants thousands to be formatted with 'K', millions with 'M' and <strike>trillions</strike> billions with <strike>'T'</strike> 'B'.

- € 1.000 -> € 1,0 K
- € 1.000.000 -> € 1,0 M
- € 1.000.000.000 -> € 1,0 B

I found the following custom format on the Internet ([here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/373449-millions-thousands-custom-number-formatting.html))

```
[>=1000000] $#,##0.0,,"M";[<1000000] $#,##0.0,"K";General
```

I adapted this to

```
[>999999] $#,##0.0,,"M";[>999] $#,##0.0,"K";General
```

Adding more conditions will result in an error.

```
[>999999999] $#,##0.0,,,"B";[>999999] $#,##0.0,,"M";[>999] $#,##0.0,"K";General
```

Finally, this seems to work when I ignore the numbers under one thousand.

```
[>999999999] $#,##0.0,,,"B";[>999999] $#,##0.0,,"M";$#,##0.0,"K"
```

In the end, I just made a formula that does the formatting, dividing the number and concatenating the €uro sign and the K, M or B.

The question is, whether there is a way to add more than two conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution, such as it is, lies in your choice of tag: Conditional Formatting. The custom formatting rules you refer to show research but seem not to meet your brother's requirement (eg `$` cf `€`) so I am uncertain what exactly the content to be formatted is and am assuming these are number values.

Also that you will be able to convert for a locale that suits you, the requirement is for Windows, not OSX, negative numbers need not be considered and Euro cents are irrelevant.

HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(A1>0,A1<1000000)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select Number tab, Category: Custom and:

```
"€ "#.0, " K"
```

OK, OK. Then another formula rule:

```
=AND(A1>999999,A1<1000000000)
```

with format:

```
"€ "#.0,, " M"
```

and a third formula rule of:

```
=A1>999999999
```

with format:

```
 "€ "#.0,,, " T"
```

The order in which the rules are applied may be significant.

Comment: I didn't think of it! Will try.